# How set different colors/backgrounds/height/width etc for each GridView item pragmatically?

Tags: android, gridview

I am trying to make this

[image]

Though i have got items in grid view but i want size /colors of items like the one in pic.

Here's my code

```
public class ImageAdapter  extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageButton imageView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageButton(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

        }
        else
        {
            imageView = (ImageButton) convertView;
        }
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setBackgroundColor(mThumbIds[0].);
        return imageView;
    }

    // Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.town_hall1,
            R.drawable.town_hall2,
            R.drawable.town_hall3,
            R.drawable.town_hall4,
            R.drawable.town_hall5,
            R.drawable.town_hall6,
            R.drawable.town_hall7,
            R.drawable.town_hall8,
            R.drawable.town_hall9,
            R.drawable.town_hall10,
            R.drawable.town_hall11,
    };
}
```

I am a beginner so kindly please provide me the steps to build that layout.
Thanks

Comment: Straggered grid view will work for your case http://www.technotalkative.com/lazy-productive-android-developer-part-6-staggered-gridview/

Answer (score 3):

if you have dummy data in `mThumbIds` then you can use switch case in `getView()` like this :

```
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageButton imageView;

    if (convertView == null) {
    switch(position){
    case 1:
        imageView = new ImageButton(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[1]);
        imageView.setBackgroundColor(mThumbIds[0].);
        break;

    case 2:
        imageView = new ImageButton(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[2]);
        imageView.setBackgroundColor(mThumbIds[0].);
        break;

    case 3:
        imageView = new ImageButton(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(50, 50));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5)
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[3]);
        imageView.setBackgroundColor(mThumbIds[0].);
        break;
     }
         }
    else
    {
        imageView = (ImageButton) convertView;
    }

    return imageView;
}
```

You can take number of case equal to number of your images. you have set different properties to different images.

Answer (score 2):

To make a `GridView` look like sample attached above you have to create class extending `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration`. 
Override `getItemOffsets()` to play around with edges and spaces as you please.

```
    public class GridSpacingItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private int spanCount;
    private int spacing;
    private boolean includeEdge;

    public GridSpacingItemDecoration(int spanCount, int spacing, boolean includeEdge) {
        this.spanCount = spanCount;
        this.spacing = spacing;
        this.includeEdge = includeEdge;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view); // item position
        int column = position % spanCount; // item column
        Log.d("position: : ", String.valueOf(Float.valueOf(position % spanCount)));

        if (includeEdge) {
            outRect.left = spacing - column * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
            outRect.right = (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // (column + 1) * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
            Log.d("spacing: ", String.valueOf(spacing));
            Log.d("spacingL: ", String.valueOf(outRect.left));

            if (position < spanCount) { // top edge
                outRect.top = spacing;
            }
            outRect.bottom = spacing; // item bottom
        } else {
            outRect.left = column * spacing / spanCount; // column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
            outRect.right = spacing - (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - (column + 1) * ((1f /    spanCount) * spacing)
            if (position >= spanCount) {
                outRect.top = spacing; // item top
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then simply call `addItemDecoration()` method on `RecyclerView` passing new instance of `GridSpacingItemDecoration` class as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get different background color for your views you can try something like this:

```
public int getRandomColor(int position) {

        int[] colorArray = {Color.RED, Color.BLACK, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, Color.DKGRAY};

        if (position > colorArray.length)
            position %= colorArray.length;

        return colorArray[position];
    }
```

Use it as:

`imageView.setBackgroundColor(getRandomColor(position));`

PS: made it without any editor so it may contain spelling errors.